# Save Images in advanced application of yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

i have a field called `photo` in model `members`. I want to access the `photo`
from both frontend and backend. So i created two folder called images in `backend\web\uploads` and `frontend\web\uploads` and my idea is to save the photo in both backend and frontend at the same time.
If i have to save an image in frontend\backend i would have used this code

```
if($model->photo  != null)
                        {
                            $model->photo->saveAs(\Yii::$app->basePath . '/web/uploads/photo/'.$model->id."_".$model->photo);

                        }
```

but i can't use this code for my purpose because i have to save it in both frontend and backend. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ideal you should create static subdomain like `static.yourdomain.com` and save images to only **one** place.

In your case you should duplicate save code to frontend and backend folders.

For example:

You can have the uploads folder inside the common folder. Your save code should now reference the folder:

```
$model->photo->saveAs('@common/uploads/photo/'.$model->id."_".$model->photo);
```

You can then save the base image url in your application's `param` configuration and use that in your views.

Answer (score 2):

you can make a symbolyc links so you don't have to save the file in both directories.

in linux just run *ln* command from a console, example you have *backend\web\uploads* directory and then you make *frontend\web\uploads* as a symbolic link to backend directory.

in linux just run:

```
ln -s backend/web/uploads frontend/web/uploads
```

in windows, open command promt, go to your yii2 directory and run:

```
mklink /D frontend\web\uploads backend\web\uploads
```

notice that *mklink* inputs is in reverse order than the *ln* command in linux

Comment: Just a note: some hosting setups do not allow user made symlinks. You may be able to get your provider to set it up for you.